# number_format in php

Tags: php, number-formatting

I have:

```
echo number_format( $uti->check_price( $rowscatpr ) , 0, '', '.' );
```

Format: **333.333.333**

I want format: **0333.333.333**

Is there a PHP function for that?

Comment: What's the logic behind this format supposed to be?

Answer (score 2):

```
$input = number_format( $uti->check_price( $rowscatpr ) , 0, '', '.' );
echo str_pad($input, strlen($input)+1, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); //0333.333.333
```

[str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)  — Pad a string to a certain length with another string.

[strlen](http://pk1.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)  — Returns the length of the given string.

Answer (score 0):

```
$v=number_format( $uti->check_price( $rowscatpr ) , 0, '', '.' );

echo str_pad($v,strlen($v)+1,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
```